# how can i output to the Command Prompt Window the same messages the source mysql command would output?

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I have a 7GB database dump from a live site i want to use as as apart of a batch file which restores a dev database on my Wamp Server. because of how big it is i expect it'll take a while to go trhough the entire file.

when i go to use

```
mysql -u [USERNAME] -p"[PASSWORD]" -D [DATABASE] -e "source dbBackup.sql"
```

it just sits there looking like it's doing nothing. bit if i went

```
mysql -u [USERNAME] -p"[PASSWORD]" -D [DATABASE]
```

then used `source dbBackup.sql` it then outputs to the Command Prompt window stuff like

> Query OK, 13896 rows affected (0.98 sec)
>   Records: 13896 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

which is what i want because then i can see that it hasn't just frozen. i've tried putting

```
mysql -u [USERNAME] -p"[PASSWORD]" -D [DATABASE]
source dbBackup.sql
exit
```

into my batch file however when it does the first line it opens up mysql like i expect it to but doesn't execute `source dbBackup.sql`. it'll work if i copy and paste those lines into the Command Prompt Window (open mysql, run `source dbBackup.sql then exit) but that kinda defeats the point of making a batch file.

So is there a way for me to get my batch file to output to the command prompt window the same output as what would using `source dbBackup.sql` give me?

NOTE: the reason why i want the messages to appear in the Command Prompt Window (as opposed to loging them in a file) is to show that something is actually working. it looks bad if i'm sitting at my work PC reading Manga with what looks to be an idle Command Prompt Window, especially if one of my bosses come in and when asked why i'm not doing my work i have to explain (again) that i am restoring my database to remove the junk test data

Comment: What about `echo source dbBackup.sql|mysql -u [USERNAME] -p"[PASSWORD]" -D [DATABASE]` or put the input into a file and redirect `mysql -u [USERNAME] -p"[PASSWORD]" -D [DATABASE] <inputfile.txt`

Comment: @LotPings tried your suggestions and they did the same as what `mysql -u [USERNAME] -p"[PASSWORD]" -D [DATABASE] -e "source dbBackup.sql"` does which is sit there looking like it's doing nothing but i know it is doing something because when i go Ctrl+C it says query aborted

Comment: It's a logical decision if mysql  doesn't output in batch mode because this would slow down the operation. To save you some keystrokes you might `echo source dbBackup.sql||clip` and when mysql is started paste from clipboard with a right mouse click. A different approach is usind vbscript sendkeys but we are talking about only some second time saving.